# Jetty error on closing context: java.lang.IllegalStateException: IDLE,initial

Tags: java, asynchronous, jetty, nio

I'm having trouble with an async jetty response! I'm using an embedded Jetty to interface with a reactor loop and collect responses as the loop process them, and then finish Jetty requests as the answers appear in a collector hash.

I'm seeing an error closing the context even when something is inside the collector hash- I think the context has timed out, and I tried to detect this and not call complete but this didn't work. I tried checking ((AsyncContinuation)ctx).isInitial() to see whether the context could be closed or not but it didn't do anything.

Here's the error:

```
INFO: e0d879983e682c0d6 API Request happens
May 25, 2012 4:39:00 AM server.Reactor$Parser parse
INFO: Received data { data from reactor }
May 25, 2012 4:39:00 AM server.AsyncHTTPRequestProcessor run
INFO: --->API http request in collector:
May 25, 2012 4:39:00 AM server.AsyncHTTPRequestProcessor run
INFO: Collector in async stuff:
2012-05-25 04:39:00.846:WARN:oejut.QueuedThreadPool:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: IDLE,initial
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncContinuation.complete(AsyncContinuation.java:569)
    at server.AsyncHTTPRequestProcessor.run(AsyncHTTPRequestProcessor.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:1119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncContinuation$1.run(AsyncContinuation.java:875)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Here's the Jetty endpoint:

```
package server;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.AsyncContext;
import javax.servlet.AsyncEvent;
import javax.servlet.AsyncListener;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.*;



public class APIRequestHandler extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -446741424265391138L;

    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, clientconnData> key2clientconn;
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<APIMessage> queue;
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> collector;
    private int timeout;
    private Logger logger;
    private Selector selector;

    public APIRequestHandler(Logger logger, Selector selector, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<APIMessage> queue,
            ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> collector, ConcurrentHashMap<String, clientconnData> key2clientconn2, int timeout)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.selector = selector;
        this.queue = queue;
        this.collector = collector;
        this.timeout = timeout;
        this.key2clientconn = key2clientconn2;
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws java.io.IOException
            {
        //System.out.println("request URI=" + req.getRequestURI());

        String rid = req.getParameter("rid");
        String clientconnId = req.getParameter("id");
        String msg = req.getParameter("json");

        // We do a null check to avoid the favicon call and other broken calls
        if(clientconnId==null || rid==null || msg==null){
            PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
            res.setStatus(200);
            res.setContentType("application/json");
            out.println("{");
            out.println("\"response\":{\"success\":\"false\",\"response\":\"request missing parameters\"}");
            out.println("}");
            out.close();
        }
        else if(!this.key2clientconn.containsKey(clientconnId))
        {
            PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
            res.setStatus(200);
            res.setContentType("application/json");
            out.println("{");
            out.println("\"rid\":"+"\""+rid+"\"");
            out.println(",");
            out.println("\"rtime\":"+0); // milliseconds
            out.println(",");
            out.println("\"response\":{\"success\":\"false\",\"response\":\"clientconn with not found on server\"}");
            out.println("}");
            out.close();
        }
        else// everything is fine, proceed as normal
        {
            logger.log(Level.INFO,"From API: "+msg);

            // Send to channel
            APIMessage m = new APIMessage();
            m.rid = rid;
            m.id = clientconnId;
            m.json = msg + "\r\n";

            // create the async context, otherwise getAsyncContext() will be null
            final AsyncContext ctx = req.startAsync();

            // set the timeout
            ctx.setTimeout(this.timeout);
            ctx.getRequest().setAttribute("rid",rid);
            ctx.getRequest().setAttribute("startTime",System.currentTimeMillis()); // start time

            // set up selector/queue
            queue.add(m);
            this.selector.wakeup();

            // attach listener to respond to lifecycle events of this AsyncContext
            ctx.addListener(new AsyncListener() {
                public void onComplete(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
                    log("onComplete called");

                    // NOTE: errors and timeouts are handled with other events.
                    // Successful comm with clientconn handled by AsyncHTTPRequestProcessor.            
                    ServletRequest asyncContextReq = event.getAsyncContext().getRequest();

                    int httpStatusCode = 500;
                    if(asyncContextReq.getAttribute("status") != null)
                        httpStatusCode = (Integer) asyncContextReq.getAttribute("status");
                    Object response = "{}";
                    if(asyncContextReq.getAttribute("response") != null)
                        response = event.getAsyncContext().getRequest().getAttribute("response");

                    long startTime = (Long) asyncContextReq.getAttribute("startTime");
                    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;

                    // Do the response
                    HttpServletResponse ctxRes = (HttpServletResponse)event.getAsyncContext().getResponse();

                    ctxRes.setStatus(httpStatusCode);
                    ctxRes.setContentType("application/json");
                    ctxRes.getWriter().println("{");
                    ctxRes.getWriter().println("\"rid\":"+"\""+asyncContextReq.getParameter("rid")+"\"");
                    ctxRes.getWriter().println(",");
                    ctxRes.getWriter().println("\"rtime\":"+elapsedTime); // milliseconds
                    ctxRes.getWriter().println(",");
                    ctxRes.getWriter().println("\"response\": "+response);

                    ctxRes.getWriter().println("}");
                    ctxRes.getWriter().flush();

                }
                public void onTimeout(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
                    log("onTimeout called");

                    // gateway timeout (on clientconn request)
                    ServletRequest asyncContextReq = event.getAsyncContext().getRequest();
                    asyncContextReq.setAttribute("status",500); // request timeout
                    asyncContextReq.setAttribute("response", "{}");
                }
                public void onError(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
                    log("onError called");

                    ServletRequest asyncContextReq = event.getAsyncContext().getRequest();
                    asyncContextReq.setAttribute("status",500); // request timeout
                    asyncContextReq.setAttribute("response", "{}");
                }
                public void onStartAsync(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
                    log("onStartAsync called");
                }
            });

            // spawn some task in a background thread
            ctx.start(new AsyncHTTPRequestProcessor(ctx,collector,logger));
        }
    }
}
```

Handling the async response:

```
package server;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.AsyncContext;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncContinuation;


public class AsyncHTTPRequestProcessor implements Runnable {

    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> collector;
    private Logger logger;
    private AsyncContext ctx;
    private String responseStr = null;

    public AsyncHTTPRequestProcessor(AsyncContext _ctx, 
            ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> _collector, Logger _logger) {
        ctx = _ctx;
        collector = _collector;
        logger = _logger;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        logger.info("AsyncContinuation start");

        //if(!((AsyncContinuation)ctx).isInitial()){
        String rid = (String) ctx.getRequest().getAttribute("rid");
        int elapsed = 0;
        if(rid !=null)
        {

            logger.info("AsyncContinuation rid="+rid);

            while(elapsed<ctx.getTimeout())
            {
                if(collector.containsKey(rid)){
                    responseStr = collector.get(rid);
                    collector.remove(rid);

                    logger.info("--->API http request in collector:"+responseStr);
                    ctx.getRequest().setAttribute("status",200);
                    ctx.getRequest().setAttribute("response", responseStr);
                    ctx.getRequest().setAttribute("endTime",System.currentTimeMillis());
                    break;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                    elapsed+=10;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //}
            logger.info("Collector in async stuff:");
            for(String key:collector.keySet()){
                logger.info(key+"->"+collector.get(key));
            }

            for(Entry<String, String> x:collector.entrySet()){
                logger.info(x.getKey()+"->"+x.getValue());
            }
            ctx.complete();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem,too.It seems that the AsyncContext.complate() method will throw the java.lang.IllegalStateException if the AsyncContext had been closed.I think that you should check you program again to find out if the AsyncContext had been closed before you called the complate() method .

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should check you program again to find out if the AsyncContext had been closed before you called the complate() method. This is effective for my problem.